# Cordova 6.0.0 Android: INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE

Tags: android, ios, cordova

*This is just an answer to my own question*

iOS runs fine, but when I tried running Android I get the following error:

```
ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Failed to install apk to emulator: pkg: /data/local/tmp/android-debug.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE]

You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
```

I've tried removing and re adding the Android platform; doesn't work.

When I tried downgrading to Cordova 5.1.1 with:

```
sudo npm install -g cordova@5.1.1
```

it works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE` is an ADB error that means you're trying to install an older version than what's already on the device. So check your app versions in your AndroidManifest.xml or gradle files, that's what it's checking - package version. Your new package needs to be either the same, or a newer (larger) version code.

You could also just delete the existing app off the emulator before you deploy again.

Comment: (BTW this is a general Android thing, nothing to do with Cordova per se.)

Comment: Thanks, that also worked!  I thought they were referring to downgrading to a previous version of cordova because I made the project when 5.1.x was the latest.

Comment: No problem! If it helped, an answer vote is always appreciated :)